# How to make a Chrome app for TeX.sx

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Not so much a question as something I hope may be useful. I'm using Chrome as my preferred browser these days, and I wanted to have an app that links to tex.sx rather than a smelly old bookmark. Here are instructions here on how to make such an app.

As this is just a glorified link, it's pretty simple. Make a new folder somewhere, and call it `tex.sx`. Next, make a new file called `manifest.json` and place this code inside:

```
{
  "name": "Tex SE",
  "description": "The Stack Exchange for TeX and friends.",
  "version": "1",
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "*://tex.stackexchange.com/"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://tex.stackexchange.com/"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "apple-touch-icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "notifications"
  ]
}
```

Next download the logo from [here](http://cdn.sstatic.net/tex/img/apple-touch-icon.png) and save it in the same folder as `apple-touch-icon.png`. Technically this should be resized to `128x128`, but it turns out that it's close enough in size that Chrome doesn't care.

Now in Chrome (19.0.x for these instructions) open the extensions viewer (under the windows menu when on OSX, and spanner->tools elsewhere) and enable Developer Mode (top right of the window). Some new options will appear, one of which is *Load unpacked extension*. Click on this and point it to the folder you created. You've now added the app, and you can disable developer mode.